# Convergence of two sequences conjecture

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If $(a_n) \rightarrow 0 $ and $(b_n - a_n) \rightarrow 0$, then $(b_n) \rightarrow a$.

I can't think of any counterexamples to this conjecture but I'm not sure how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean $a_n\rightarrow a$?

Comment: Would $ a = 0 $ in this case?

Comment: What exactly is $a$?

Comment: I think $a = lim(a_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that $a_n\to a$.

$0\le|b_n-a|=|b_n-a_n+a_n-a|\le|b_n-a_n|+|a_n-a|\to0$